# Why do some php functions 'return' a given parameter?

Tags: php, function

I'm not sure if I've phrased this question appropriately but I don't know how else to pose it without giving examples, which I will do.

**Examples:**

*preg_match*

```
preg_match("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Why do we give preg_match the parameter of `$output_array`? It seems not to make sense in the context of how the rest of php works. Wouldn't the following be more conventional?

```
$output_array = preg_match("/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/", $input_line);
```

---

*openssl_private_encrypt*

```
openssl_private_encrypt ($data , $encrypted_data , $key);
```

Again, why do we pass the `$encrypted_data` to the function? Rather than what 99% of other functions do and return the result which can be used to set a variable's value.

```
$encrypted_data = openssl_private_encrypt ($data, $key);
```

---

Is this a legacy issue? Are there good reasons for doing this with certain functions?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because those functions were previously part of other projects and imported into PHP.

Comment: First you have to keep two things apart: the result whether the regular expression matches or not, which is what is returned and what makes sense from a linguistic point of view: "if preg matches then...". And on the other hand an _optional_ capture array. How would you want to express the fact that this is optional otherwise? You'd have to define the function signature such that it returns a "mixed" type, a nightmare for all programmers, since the type of the result depends on the input, not on the implementation!

Comment: @aynber Sorry, no that is definitely not the reason.

Comment: @arkascha Like I said, it was a guess. :-)

Comment: I was just going to say `preg_match()` returns a boolean already ... I think I prefer @arkascha comment.

Comment: @CD001 - quirkily, `preg_match()` actually returns an int (0 or 1), or a boolean; I asume to maintain a degree of compatibility with `preg_match_all()`

Comment: I always use it to check of it properly executed. $a = big_function. Because those functions always return a bool

Comment: @MarkBaker ... hmmm looking at the docs, it's `1` (match) `0` (no match) or `FALSE` (something went wrong) - which is likely to raise an error I'd guess... so it's an int or a boolean. Gotta love php, it has "character"

Comment: PHP is written in C and there was sort of a "standard" in C when it comes to error reporting in that all functions return a status code and the actual return  value is passed as an argument pointer. I'm guessing people working on those PHP features thought it would make sense if PHP itself followed the same convention.

Comment: @arkascha I can see the logic of what you are saying but it doesn't answer examples like the `openssl` family of functions. Also `preg_match()` has to run the regex on the input, and therefore use the same computation if it an output array was used or not. Surely the function should return the array by default and it is up to the programmer to respond to either an empty array, a non-empty array, or potentially a `FALSE` in the case something went wrong. Although ideally it should be a thrown error.

Comment: @Samyoul `openssl_private_encrypt` produces a binary value, which is potentially indistinguishable from a returned falsey value, and would require explicit `=== false` comparison. While that's a legitimate design decision too (see `strpos` for example), the designers of the openssl API chose to make it less ambiguous and clearly return a boolean and the crypted value separately.

Comment: Because PHP is a rather sloppily designed language and because it's collected a lot of cruft over the years.  It also tends to expose the API of the libraries it uses by directly replicating that API's calling conventions.  preg_match reflects the PCRE library's interface, whereas openssl_private_encrypt reflects the OpenSSL library's interface.

Comment: @GordonM And now explain why *those* libraries chose that particular interface… :o)

Comment: @Samyoul You wrote "Surely the function should return the array by default and ..." I totally disagree. That would be a nightmare for all programmers. You'd have to use complex conditionals to try to interpret whatever you got back from that function. _Why?_ It is much more convenient and precise the way it currently is solved. Don't get me wrong: there are issues with function signatures in php (string functions). But `preg_match()` is an example for a well crafted, thoughtfully designed interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PHP isn't big on throwing exceptions in the good old core standard library, it needs a different mechanism to distinguish two aspects of a function's operation:

- did the operation succeed?
- what's the return value, if any?

Languages which build more on exceptions would have something like this:

```
try:
    value = somefunc()
except SomeError:
    # handle failure
```

Languages like Go return a return value *and* an error status indicator:

```
value, err := somefunc()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

PHP instead uses the `return` value as the success indicator and a by-reference parameter as return value, especially when that return value is not always of interest:

```
if (!somefunc($value)) {
    // handle failure
}
echo $value;
```

Otherwise code would have to look something like this:

```
$value = somefunc();
if ($value === false) {
    // handle failure
} else if ($value === 0) {
    // no match
}
echo $value;
```

In some cases using the return value both for error indication *and* return value is impossible, since `false` or `0` or both may be a legitimate return value and you couldn't distinguish it from an error code. Using by-reference parameters for "secondary" return values is not a terrible design decision, if you're not going to use exceptions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with exceptions. If a regular expression doesn't match, it isn't an exception or error, it just doesn't match, which is a perfectly fine result. Check @arkasha's comment above, which imo is the answer to this question.

Comment: @giorgio I'm illustrating the difference between a *return value* and an indication that an *error occurred*, and that both need separate signalling mechanisms. I'm purposefully using an undefined `somefunc`, not `preg_match`. How that concept is applied to individual functions is left up to the individual API. FWIW, `preg_match` can also return `false` as one of its possible return values, which should really be an exception.

Comment: Having said all of this, PHP isn't exactly a stellar example of great and/or consistent API design…

Comment: Reading the responses so far, @deceze your answer makes the most sense. When comparing to other php functions that have the behaviour I'm describing, your answer fits. PHP is trying to signal two things simultaneously using the same method, rather than using exceptions to signal failures.

Comment: *"Having said all of this, PHP isn't exactly a stellar example of great and/or consistent API design…"* ... I'm looking at you `$GLOBALS` without your little underscore!